# MYSQL to CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to convert following complex mysql into cake's find expression:

```
SELECT p1, p2
FROM
  (
    SELECT IFNULL(a.c2, '10') AS p1, IFNULL((SELECT MAX(c.c1) FROM my_table c WHERE c.c1>p1), '30') AS p2
    FROM my_table a
    WHERE
    (
      (a.user_id = 2) AND (a.c1 BETWEEN '10' AND '30')
    )

  ) as temp
WHERE p2 > 100
ORDER BY p1;
```

I tried following
http://dogmatic69.com/sql-to-cakephp-find-converter
but unable to generate the desired expression.

Please help. I really don't know how to handle such complex expressions (I do not prefer to use query in cakephp)

Thanks

Comment: have you hired someone here ...

Answer (score 0):

Let me just convert your query into the cakephp way
if table a's model is A:

```
$fields = "IFNULL(A.c2, '10') AS p1, IFNULL((SELECT MAX(C.c1) FROM my_table c WHERE C.c1>p1), '30')    AS p2";
$conditions = "A.user_id=2 AND A.c1 BETWEEN '10' AND '30'";
$inner_querry = $this->A->find("all", compact("fields", "conditions"));

$fields = "p1,p2";
$conditions = "p1 IN ($inner_querry) AND p2 IN($inner_query) AND p2 > 100";
$order = "p1";
$query = $this->A->find("all", compact("fields", "conditions", "order"));

debug($query); //check results of for error.
```

Comment: `$inner_query` (with one single 'r') returns an indexed array and not a string, `$fields` should be an array and not a string and finally I don't think the result of your query would be the same of the question's one

Comment: maybe we can implode the inner_query to return some strings

Answer (score 0):

I think that sometimes it's not so wrong to use Model->query(), but let' try to use cake functions.

In fact the only way I see to obtain that particular query is building the subqueries with buildStatement() function (and at the end you still have to call Model->query() so...). But just for fun.

Assuming your model name is MyTable, in your MyTablesController do:

```
$p1 = "IFNULL(a.c2, '10') AS p1";

$db = $this->MyTable->getDataSource();

$subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
        array(
            'table'      => $db->fullTableName($this->MyTable),
            'alias'      => 'C',
            'fields'     => array('MAX(c.c1)'),
            'conditions' => array(
                "C.c1 > " => 'p1', 
            )
        ),
        $this->MyTable
    );

$p2 = "IFNULL(".$subQuery.") AS p2";

$subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
        array(
            'table'      => $db->fullTableName($this->MyTable),
            'alias'      => 'A',
            'fields'     => array($p1, $p2),
            'conditions' => array(
                "A.user_id" => 2, 
                "A.c1 BETWEEN ? AND ?" => array(10,30) 
            )
        ),
        $this->MyTable
    );

$query = $db->buildStatement(
        array(
            'table'      => $subQuery,
            'alias'      => 'test',
            'fields'     => array('p1', 'p2'),
            'conditions' => array(
                "p2 > " => 100, 
            )
        ),
        $this->MyTable
    );
```